# I want to use shell scripting to run my java program for each of my input files

Tags: java, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a directory of input files and I want to use a shell script to execute these files onto the console and then create output files in a new output directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES="inputs/*.txt"
for f in $FILES
do
    basename=${f%.*}
    java main accounts.txt rentalunits.txt
    cat "$f"
    
done >> $basename.out
```

I tried running this code using

```
sh testscript
```

for two text files but it only creates one output file and gets stuck at the first scanner in the java program.

Comment: What scanner in the java program? The java program is being run multiple times with the same arguments in a loop why?

Comment: For each input test file I want to crate a new output file. The first scanner asks for a command which is on the first line of the input file, which would then proceed to the next line and so on.

Comment: All the output of your for loop is being appended to the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES="inputs/*.txt"
for f in $FILES
do
    basename=${f%.*}
    java main accounts.txt rentalunits.txt < "$f" > "$basename.out"
done
```

Also, no need to specify the interpreter as you have the shebang

```
chmod +x testscript
./testcript
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got your answer, but the correct way to loop over the files of a glob pattern is:

```sh
for f in inputs/*.txt; do ...
```

i.e. don't put the pattern in a variable: it forces you to leave your variables unquoted which may have unintended consequences.

If you want to use a variable, in bash use an array:

```sh
files=( inputs/*.txt )
for f in "${files[@]}"; do ...
```

and now, because of the bash-specific features, you have to use `bash ./testscript` not `sh`